# shorter way to get number of rows in a table

Tags: php, mysql

```
$sql = "select id from images";
$st = $db->prepare($sql);
$st->execute();
$total = $st->rowCount();
echo $total;
```

Do I really need all the above to get number of rows in a table? Is there a shorter way?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM images` will return the number of rows in the table.

Comment: @Dave and how to get this as a php variable? Do I need again `$sql = ... $st = ...`

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Even shorter, lose the `prepare/execute` and use `query` since you're not using a prepared statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use count to retrieve the number of rows in a table.

```
$st = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM images');
$total = $st->fetchColumn();
echo $total;
```

*(Thanks to Funk Forty Niner for the hint to remove the prepare/execute completely)*

Comment: This can be even shorter.

Comment: Edit away sir! :)

Comment: [It's in my comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53600759/shorter-way-to-get-number-of-rows-in-a-table#comment94066115_53600759).

Comment: Thanks. I'm afraid php and mysql are not so good friends as one can find everywhere on the net. Four lines to get number of rows is to much. It should be like `givemecount('images')`

Comment: Would have been nice to hand a credit plug ;-) Seeing the edit. This wasn't my show. I think you understand. But now, it seems like the plot has thickened, given the OP's comment here.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what to say in response to that.

Comment: @puerto That's a ridiculous thing to say. If you want a function to execute an arbitrary SQL statement like `select count(*) from images`, then just write the function. PHP is a general purpose language, not a thin wrapper around SQL.

Comment: @meagar, in that case someone should write a `thin wrapper around SQL` and then give them the title - `the perfect language pair...` etc

Comment: I'm amazed that you want one less line of code @puerto. A wrapper is going to add overhead and, in the end, not really buy you anything at all.

Comment: @puerto You can Install an ORM and move on to more important questions about the app you're writing. There are far more important things than how many lines if code you have to write to execute a `select count(*) from <table>` query.